# Calling a function inside a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I know there is something wrong in my logic. Here is a snippet of my JS file:

```
$("#sign").submit(function () {
        if (SIGN === IN) 
             signin_account($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
        else 
             $("#sign").submit();
});
```

Please help me fix this. The setup is I have a form which is dynamic, could be a sign-in or a sign-up form. The value of SIGN tells if the form is a sign-up or a sign-in. If it is a sign-in form, it will check first if the account details through the function signn_account(). If it is a sign-up form, it will going to submit the form.

What I want is when the event submit() is called, I will check first the input for errors(wrong password, no username exists, etc.). Now, if there is no error, I am going to **really submit** the form to a script(php, cgi, etc) which makes the event submit() called again.

The script to handle the sign-in form and the sign-up form is different.

I am new to JS, huhu.

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: What does the IN variable store? Or, is it a string value?

Comment: My problem is,  I am calling an event(the submit()) inside one event handler. Thus, I am getting "maximum stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: Are you sure that your `SIGN === IN` is ever evaluating to true? I'd put a `console.log()` in there to be sure.

Comment: Yes, yes. I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$("#sign").submit();` in the `else` block is the conflict. When the value of `SIGN` is not `IN`, there will be an infinite loop --- `$("#sign").submit();` will going to call the function again. You should try to make another function for the `else` block.